# Twitter bootstrap mix horizontal form with inline

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im trying to make inline form mixed with horizontal
I have http://jsfiddle.net/TNLnP/3/ but I want to get something like

```
<label><input>
<label><input><label><input><label><input>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to keep both within the same `form` element you can add `form-inline` to your `fieldset`:

```
<form>
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label">A</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-medium">
    </fieldset>
</div><!-- end row -->
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label">B</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
        <label class="control-label">C</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
        <label class="control-label">D</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
        <label class="control-label">E</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
    </fieldset>
</div><!-- end row -->
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWNjw/

Comment: Just adding that if you need an horizontal form (as stated in the question) with inline elements, this answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap
I was looking for this today and ended up here.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!-- First Form =============================== -->
<div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
      <label class="control-label">A</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-medium">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div><!-- end row -->

<!-- Second Form ================================== -->
<div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
      <label class="control-label">B</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
      <label class="control-label">C</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
      <label class="control-label">D</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
      <label class="control-label">E</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-mini" >
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Try this at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eB39A/). Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I think the main issue is keeping them w/in the same form