# Twitter Bootstrap - help-inline or help-block for radio/checkbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the proper way to mark up `help-inline` or `help-block` for a radio or chechbox field?

This is not displaying as I would expect it to:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
            <label class="radio" for="foo">
                <input type="radio" name="foobar" value="foo" id="foo">
                Foo label
            </label>
            <span class="help-inline">Foo inline help</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Follow up question: how do I mark up the second radio option? Wrapped in another `div.controls`?

Answer (score 0):

See [Simbirsk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12212196/1242785) - helped me:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Type</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputType" placeholder="Type">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <span class="control-label">Metadata</span>
        <div class="controls form-inline">
            <label for="inputKey">Key</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Key" id="inputKey">
            <label for="inputValue">Value</label>
            <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Value" id="inputValue">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that I'm using `.form-inline` to get the propper styling inside a `.controls`.
You can test it on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/nbwNf/) jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to also write what do you actually expect. I'll have to guess on your expectations here and propose the following solution:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio" for="foo">
            <input id="IsActivated" name="IsActivated" type="radio" value="true">
            Is Activated
            <span class="help-inline">Foo inline help</span>
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

We implemented it as follows:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="foo">Foo label</label>

   <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
         <input id="foo" name="foo" type="radio">
         Foo message
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Two labels for one field? It's semantically incorrect and invalid mark up.