# How to output django_filters.RangeFilter text boxes inline?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-filter

How to output django_filters.RangeFilter textboxes inline?

[image: How to output <code>django_filters.RangeFilter</code> textboxes inline?]

I use [django_filters](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) and [django-bootstrap-form](https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form)

My template.html

```
<div class="row">       
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
        {{ filter.form|bootstrap_horizontal }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have several text filters in filterset, and I want to place in horizontal, and only RangeFilter are inline.

Comment: Are you using django bootstrap form’s?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form

Comment: Read the  README.rst of the app.It said, to use class="form-inline" on the form element, also change the "|boostrap" template tag to "|bootstrap_inline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ filter.form|bootstrap_inline }}
```

OR

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
```

To use class="form-inline" on the form element, also change the "|boostrap" template tag to "|bootstrap_inline".

Comment: Can I mix inline and horizontal elements on one form?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap