# In Bootstrap, group together two items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, how do I force two items - a label and a textbox - to act as an inseparable group, so that they always appear on the same line, and never get broken, with the label at the end of one line and the textbox at the beginning of the next line?

Comment: You are probably willing to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I did read those solutions, but none of them successfully handled the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish which (other than adding `class="form-horizontal"` to the `form` element is mostly adjusting the column size (ie xs-3, sm-9, md-1 and  etc) to see what makes sense based on your the character length of the label.

Most of the CSS that's included you don't need to achieve this; it's centered on the page otherwise the inputs will become the width of the column and also the background color of the form will change once you reach a mobile phones view port since your form could start to breakdown with labels fixed to one side.

All of these things can be adjusted as it applies to your need either way.

```css
#boostrapForm .control-label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
#boostrapForm input[type=text],
#boostrapForm input[type=email],
#boostrapForm input[type=password],
{
  margin-left: -7px;
}
.formCenter {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.formCenter.formChange {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .formCenter.formChange {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 359px) {
  form {
    background: #f00;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="formCenter formChange">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="boostrapForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working as I'd hoped, but the mark-up that you've supplied may provide a basis for what I'm looking for - much trial and error is necessary, as I am a newcomer to Bootstrap.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you're able to post a mockup/image or link that displays what you're trying to do that would be ideal because it's honestly unclear currently.

Comment: Sorry - I can't figure out how to insert a .jpg file that illustrates what I want.  I will try to describe it again:  If I have a 'Name' label, followed by a text box, followed by an 'ID' label, followed by another textbox, then I never want to see 'Name'  <textbox1>  'ID' on one line and <textbox2> on another line.