# bootstrap input form-control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there anyway to get boostrap's `form-control` for `input` to be inline without using the grid system i.e. `col-md-2`?

Because this is the only feature of bootstrap that I find astoundingly annoying.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:[Form inline inside form-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: @RemyaCV Not really since that still uses the grid system of `col-md-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try is :-

```
  <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
     </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

It should work.... there's a class **.form-inline** to make the form-control display inline.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made a workaround.

`<input type="text" class="input-sm" style='box-shadow: none; border: 1px solid lightgray'>`

This makes it look like bootstrap's text input without it taking up an entire row or requiring you to play with the grid system.

If anyone has a better answer feel free to make your input