# How to add To label and input in one line (HTML)

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make a Two label and input in one line can anyone help me to build these forms like this. I want to make this like this image. i need to make input below the label and them in one line[Image](https://i.stack.i)

```css
.first_line_left,.first_line_right,.first_line_right_far{
 float: left;width:50%;box-sizing: border-box;
}
label,input{
 width:10%,float:left;box-sizing:border-box;
}
input{
 padding: 8px 10px;box-sizing: border-box;
}
.first_line_left,.first_line_right,.first_line_right_far{
 width: 33.33%;float: left;padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
 <title>form</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
<body>
 <h1>Personal Details</h1><hr>
<form action="" method="post">

<div class="First_line_left">
 <label for="title">Title</label>
 <select>
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>

 </select>
</div>
<div class="First_line_right">
 <label for="Delegate_First_name">Delegate First</label>
 
<input type="text" name="Delegate_First_name" placeholder="Delegate First name">
</div>
<div class="First_line_right_far">
<label for="Delegate_last_name">Delegate last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Delegate_last_name" placeholder="Delegate last Name">
</div>


</div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

mgur.com/Muvyh.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CSS to make the form style like that.
I have created an example code in JS fiddle based on your requirements.

https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/8vu73Lso/8/

```css
.left_half,.right_half{width:50%;float:left;padding:10px;box-sizing: border-box;}
label,input,select{width:100%;float:left;box-sizing: border-box;}
input{padding:8px 10px;box-sizing: border-box;}
.first_left,.first_center,.first_right{width:33.33%;float:left;padding:10px;box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<html>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="left_half">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
</div>
<div class="right_half">
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone">
</div>
<div class="first_left">
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
</div>
<div class="first_center">
<label>Comments</label>
<input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment">
</div>
<div class="first_right">
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject">
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: added changes in CSS. I have added support for the SELECT element as well. Do upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the label appear beside the input field, or make the input fields appear side by side as seen in your picture?

If you are using bootstrap, you may find this solution helpful: [Form inline inside a form horizontal in twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: I want to make just like image